# How can I create specific color scheme in Mathematica

Tags: color

Is it possible to create a `Color Scheme` like the one below?

[image]

Comment: If neither `ColorData["RedBlueTones"]` nor `ColorData["ThermometerColors"]` suit your needs, you might want to mention first where you got that color gradient from.

Comment: @J.M., I am aware of Mathematica color schemes, and the color scheme I posted I think it is one of matplotlib schemes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSxA8.png"];
```

Get the colors from `img`:

```
dc = DominantColors[img]
```

[image]

Manually sort them as desired:

```
cl = dc[[{5, 3, 6, 1, 7, 4, 2, 8}]]
```

[image]

Use the sorted color list with `Blend` and use it with `BarLegend`:

```
BarLegend[{Blend[cl, Rescale[#, {-2, 2}]] &, {-2, 2}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 300}, LabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

(Not exactly the same as the image in your post, but this should give you an idea.)

With additional manual tweaks we can get closer to the reference image:

```
cf = Blend[{{-2, cl[[1]]}, {-3/2, cl[[2]]}, {-1, cl[[3]]}, {0, White}, 
  {1, cl[[-3]]}, {3/2, cl[[-2]]}, {2, cl[[-1]]}}, #] &;

BarLegend[{cf, {-2, 2}}, LegendMarkerSize -> {50, 300}, 
 LabelStyle -> 16]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, @kglr, That is AWESOME! now I can create any color schemes I like from other platforms.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to implement the "RdBu" colormap from [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) (or any other colormap, really), you can always look at **[the source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/06567e021f21be046b6d6dcf00380c1cb9adaf3c/lib/matplotlib/_cm.py)** to extract the colors being used internally, so that you can feed them to `Blend[]`.

In particular,

```
With[{cols = RGBColor /@ {"#053061", "#2166ac", "#4393c3", "#92c5de", 
                          "#d1e5f0", "#f7f7f7", "#fddbc7", "#f4a582",
                          "#d6604d", "#b2182b", "#67001f"}},
     RdBuMap = Blend[cols, #] &];

LinearGradientImage[RdBuMap, {600, 60}]
```

[image: RdBu color gradient]

```
BarLegend[{RdBuMap[Rescale[#, {-2, 2}]] &, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: legend with RdBu colormap]

---

As another example, here is the "coolwarm" diverging colormap, also from Matplotlib:

```
With[{cols = RGBColor /@
      {"#3b4cc0", "#445acc", "#4d68d7", "#5775e1", "#6282ea", "#6c8ef1",
       "#779af7", "#82a5fb", "#8db0fe", "#98b9ff", "#a3c2ff", "#aec9fd",
       "#b8d0f9", "#c2d5f4", "#ccd9ee", "#d5dbe6", "#dddddd", "#e5d8d1",
       "#ecd3c5", "#f1ccb9", "#f5c4ad", "#f7bba0", "#f7b194", "#f7a687", 
       "#f49a7b", "#f18d6f", "#ec7f63", "#e57058", "#de604d", "#d55042",
       "#cb3e38", "#c0282f", "#b40426"}}, 
     CoolWarmMap = Blend[cols, #] &];

LinearGradientImage[CoolWarmMap, {600, 60}]
```

[image: coolwarm color gradient]

```
BarLegend[{CoolWarmMap[Rescale[#, {-2, 2}]] &, {-2, 2}}]
```

[image: legend with coolwarm colormap]

Comment: thanks for the precise and detailed answer, @J. M.